# Set axios header

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a class like the following:

```
import axios from "axios";

//axios.defaults.headers["Email"] = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
//axios.defaults.headers["Access-Token"] = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');

class Api {
    // users
    static getUsers(params={}) { return axios.get("users", {params}) }
    static getUser(userId) { return axios.get("users/" + userId) }
    static updateUser(userId, data) { return axios.put("users/" + userId, data) }        

    // other resources...
}
```

By reading Axios documentation I see that I can set the header for each request by doing something as follows:

```
axios.defaults.headers["Email"] = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
axios.defaults.headers["Access-Token"] = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
```

If I insert these 2 lines outside the class at the beggining of the file, I do get an error because sessionStorage hasn't been set yet. After a refresh though sessionStorage gets set so everything works fine.

How could I solve this issue? I would like to keep the axios calls as short as they are right now.

Comment: from where are the `access_tokens` and the `email` coming from?

Comment: I set them after logging in, inside another file... I don't think it should matter where I set them

Comment: well you could wrap the code that retrieves those values in a promise and when these values are retrieved then you could call your other functions l

Comment: could you please show me an example?

Comment: here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/yqtrrreb/. without seeing the setup of your code to retrieve the token and email it is a bit difficult to provide a concrete answer but hopefully the jsfiddle helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using OOP I will suggest to use a constructor and  some dependency injection to make your life easier.

Use a constructor like this:

```
constructor(email, accessToken) {
  axios.defaults.headers["Email"] = email
  // same thing for accessToken
}
```

If you are using axios in some  other places that share the same headers I would suggest initialize axios with the app, some  "main" kind of file, set the defaults values and instead of passing `email` and `accessToken` just pass the axios instance like:

```
constructor(axios) {
  this.axios = axios // without importing axios
}
// and use like that
this.axios.get("users", {params})
```

Other suggestions would be pass axios instance directly to your methods like:

```
static getUsers(axios, params={}) { return axios.get("users", {params}) }
```

I would highly suggest to avoid to depend on sessionStorage on the class, since you don't know when that would load or be executed. It's just better to have that explicitly telling where it's coming from. Also would be easier to test.

Comment: I'm using a library that let my Rails backend communicate some info to my redux frontend: ReactOnRails. The method is the one that initializes by Redux store. I know that this is a little hacky but this is what i got for now. The only way to have these 2 pieces of informations in a clean way is the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
 axios.defaults.headers.common["token"] = action.payload.data.token;
```

Comment: do you want to asign default headers in axios comunication?  here are you are, import library axios and then assign the value...

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1346

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `interceptors` in the `axios`. You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by then or catch.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
           // Do something before request is sent
           axios.defaults.headers["Email"] = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
           axios.defaults.headers["Access-Token"] = token;
           return config;
         }, function (error) {
            // Do something with request error
            return Promise.reject(error);
         });
```

for more details : https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score -1):

you could set the headers each time you call axios (even if the calls are a bit longer :

```js
import axios from "axios";


class Api {
    // users
    static getUsers(params={}) { 
      params.headers = params.headers || {}
      params.headers["Email"] = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
      params.headers["Access-Token"] = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
      return axios.get("users", {params}) 
    }
    static getUser(userId, params={}) { 
      params.headers = params.headers || {}
      params.headers["Email"] = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
      params.headers["Access-Token"] = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
      return axios.get("users/" + userId, params) 
     }
    static updateUser(userId, data, params={}) { 
      params.headers = params.headers || {}
      params.headers["Email"] = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
      params.headers["Access-Token"] = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
      return axios.put("users/" + userId, data, params) 
    }        

    // other resources...
}
```

Not the shortest, but I think it could do the job.

I hope it helps.

Maxime

Comment: I explicitly asked "I would like to keep the Axios calls as short as they are right now"